# Use ISIN to retrieve stock data in PYTHON

Tags: python, finance, stock, price

In my quest of retrieving the stock prices, in daily, within a 10y period, of the 600 companies of the index EUROSTOXX 600, I'm facing some difficulties.

First question : Retrieving all of this with one part of code seems feasible according to you ?
(I'm considering adding also main financial indicators like ROI,ROE,EBIT,EPS, annual performance... and export all of this on one excel sheet)

I collected all the 600 ISIN. The question is, can I use it to retrieve the data from yahoo finance (or anything else) or should I find a way to find the 600 real tickers defined by Yahoo ?

If yes, does anyone have a tip for that ? I've been looking for lists but this index doesn't look very popular apparently.

Thank you for reading !

Comment: See How to male a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2824732